# Page is cropped in new document in PDFBox while copying

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to split the single PDF into multiple. Like 10 page document into 10 single page document.

```
PDDocument source = PDDocument.load(input_file);
PDDocument output = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = source.getPages().get(0);
output.addPage(page);
output.save(file);
output.close();
```

Here the problem is, the new document's page size is different than original document. So some text are cropped or missing in new document. I am using PDFBox 2.0 and how I can avoid this?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks @mkl.

Splitter did the magic. Here is the updated working part,

```
public static void extractAndCreateDocument(SplitMeta meta, PDDocument source)
      throws IOException {

    File file = new File(meta.getFilename());

    Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
    splitter.setStartPage(meta.getStart());
    splitter.setEndPage(meta.getEnd());
    splitter.setSplitAtPage(meta.getEnd());

    List<PDDocument> docs = splitter.split(source);
    if(docs.size() > 0){
      PDDocument output = docs.get(0);
      output.save(file);
      output.close();
    }
  }

public class SplitMeta {

  private String filename;
  private int start;
  private int end;

  public SplitMeta() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately you don't share a sample document to reproduce the issue. I would assume that the PDF page in question has inherited properties which are not copied over by `PDDocument.addPage`. Can you share a sample document to analyze?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the OP has not provided a sample document to reproduce the issue. Thus, I have to guess.

I assume that the issue is based in objects not immediately linked to the page object but inherited from its parents.

In that case using `PDDocument.addPage` is the wrong choice as this method only adds the given page object to the target document page tree without consideration of inherited stuff.

Instead one should use `PDDocument.importPage` which is documented as:

```
/**
 * This will import and copy the contents from another location. Currently the content stream is stored in a scratch
 * file. The scratch file is associated with the document. If you are adding a page to this document from another
 * document and want to copy the contents to this document's scratch file then use this method otherwise just use
 * the {@link #addPage} method.
 * 
 * Unlike {@link #addPage}, this method does a deep copy. If your page has annotations, and if
 * these link to pages not in the target document, then the target document might become huge.
 * What you need to do is to delete page references of such annotations. See
 * <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/35477351/535646">here</a> for how to do this.
 *
 * @param page The page to import.
 * @return The page that was imported.
 * 
 * @throws IOException If there is an error copying the page.
 */
public PDPage importPage(PDPage page) throws IOException
```

Actually even this method might not suffice as is as it does not consider all inherited attributes, but looking at the `Splitter` utility class one gets an impression what one has to do:

```
PDPage imported = getDestinationDocument().importPage(page);
imported.setCropBox(page.getCropBox());
imported.setMediaBox(page.getMediaBox());
// only the resources of the page will be copied
imported.setResources(page.getResources());
imported.setRotation(page.getRotation());
// remove page links to avoid copying not needed resources 
processAnnotations(imported);
```

making use of the helper method

```
private void processAnnotations(PDPage imported) throws IOException
{
    List<PDAnnotation> annotations = imported.getAnnotations();
    for (PDAnnotation annotation : annotations)
    {
        if (annotation instanceof PDAnnotationLink)
        {
            PDAnnotationLink link = (PDAnnotationLink)annotation;   
            PDDestination destination = link.getDestination();
            if (destination == null && link.getAction() != null)
            {
                PDAction action = link.getAction();
                if (action instanceof PDActionGoTo)
                {
                    destination = ((PDActionGoTo)action).getDestination();
                }
            }
            if (destination instanceof PDPageDestination)
            {
                // TODO preserve links to pages within the splitted result  
                ((PDPageDestination) destination).setPage(null);
            }
        }
        // TODO preserve links to pages within the splitted result  
        annotation.setPage(null);
    }
}
```

**As you are *trying to split the single PDF into multiple, like 10 page document into 10 single page document,* you might want to use this `Splitter` utility class as is.**

### Tests

To test those methods I used the output of the PDF Clown sample output [AnnotationSample.Standard.pdf](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/raw/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/merge/AnnotationSample.Standard.pdf) because that library heavily depends on inheritance of page tree values. Thus, I copied the content of its only page to a new document using either `PDDocument.addPage`, `PDDocument.importPage`, or `Splitter` like this:

```
PDDocument source = PDDocument.load(resource);
PDDocument output = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = source.getPages().get(0);
output.addPage(page);
output.save(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "PageAddedFromAnnotationSample.Standard.pdf"));
output.close();
```

*([CopyPages.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/merge/CopyPages.java#L42) test `testWithAddPage`)*

```
PDDocument source = PDDocument.load(resource);
PDDocument output = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = source.getPages().get(0);
output.importPage(page);
output.save(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "PageImportedFromAnnotationSample.Standard.pdf"));
output.close();
```

*([CopyPages.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/merge/CopyPages.java#L68) test `testWithImportPage`)*

```
PDDocument source = PDDocument.load(resource);
Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
List<PDDocument> results = splitter.split(source);
Assert.assertEquals("Expected exactly one result document from splitting a single page document.", 1, results.size());
PDDocument output = results.get(0);
output.save(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "PageSplitFromAnnotationSample.Standard.pdf"));
output.close();
```

*([CopyPages.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/merge/CopyPages.java#L95) test `testWithSplitter`)*

Only the final test copied the page faithfully.