# The PDF has been Split using PDF Box library and the resultant PDF has almost same size as source PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using the below code to split the huge PDF into two different PDF. The PDF is splitting properly. The first PDF will be generated with first 2 pages of PDF and 2nd PDF will be generated with the rest of the pages of PDF.

The problem is the size, the source PDF is 17 MB. *The 2 PDF's  that are generated are also of 15MB each*. Logically it should be less in size, I searched the forum, they said PDFont has to be used properly. I haven't used PDFont here not sure If Im doing it wrongly

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, COSVisitorException {

            File input = new File("sourceFile.pdf");

           // pdPage and pdPage1 will be used to get first and second page of entire PDF
//pdPageMedRec will get the rest of the pages
            PDPage pdPage = null;
            PDPage pdPage1 = null;
            PDPage pdPageMedRec = null;

            PDDocument firstOutputDocument = null;
            PDDocument secondOutputDocument = null;
            PDDocument inputDocument = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(input, null);
            List<PDPage> list = inputDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();


       // I wanted two documents to be generated from the big PDF
//firstOutputDocument  is document 1 and it will be having first 2 pages of the big pdf
//secondOutputDocument is document 2 and it will be having the rest of the pages of the PDF
            firstOutputDocument = new PDDocument();
            secondOutputDocument = new PDDocument();

// Taking first page and second page
            pdPage = list.get(0);
            pdPage1 = list.get(1);

// Appending them as one document
            firstOutputDocument.importPage(pdPage);
            firstOutputDocument.importPage(pdPage1);

// Looping the rest of the pages
            for (int page = 3; page <= inputDocument.getNumberOfPages(); ++page) {
                pdPageMedRec = (PDPage) inputDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(page - 1);
                // append page to current document
                secondOutputDocument.importPage(pdPageMedRec);
            }

// Saving first document
            File f = new File("document1.pdf");
            firstOutputDocument.save(f);
            firstOutputDocument.close();

// Saving second document
            File g = new File("document2.pdf");
            secondOutputDocument.save(g);
            secondOutputDocument.close();

            inputDocument.close();
        }
```

Comment: *"Logically it should be less in size"* - not necessarily. If the pages share a large amount of resources, that result may be appropriate. Without the PDF to reproduce the issue, it is difficult to analyze it.

Comment: @mkl I agree. The PDF i'm having contains a lot of images and text contents along with tables in it. I don't have the liberty to share it. But I want to understand if my code is performing correct? or I'm doing something wrong appending the pages using OutputDocument.importPage()

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using? Hopefully 2.0.13. See also the warning in the javadoc of importpage, "...then the target document might become huge".

Comment: @Vibin *"But I want to understand if my code is performing correct?"* - Your code does not look unreasonable. Depending on the internal nature of your source document, though, some specific additions might be appropriate.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I'm using the PDF BOX jar of version 1.8.4. This version do not have PDF Font Box JAR available in it. So I have added 1.8.4 version of PDF Font Box as external JAR and using it.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Is this the one? https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#addPage(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage)

Comment: The current version is 2.0.13. The current 1.8 version is 1.8.15. Please don't use antique versions unless you like software archeology. You used `importPage()`, thus you should look at the javadoc of it, not of another method.

Comment: The current javadoc would have pointed to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35477351/535646